# How do i select particular column from my table in sql

Tags: sql, select

How do I select particular column from table,For example if i have 100 columns in my table and want only 20th-30th column to display . How it is possible in sql?

Comment: select columnname from table is the standard way ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to select columns by their ordinal number in, for example, MySQL, but you should *not* be relying on these positions because they can change, and the order is not guaranteed.

The same holds true with regard to the location of rows (records) within your table.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
select * from table
```

use

```
select nameOfCol20, nameOfcol21, ..., nameOfCol30 from table
```